# Architecture in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, assembly, x86, pdp-11

How can I change architecture in Eclipse from `x86` to `pdp11`, what flags do I need, and do I need adjust cross-compiler, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't since a [PDP-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) is a 16bit computer it can't be equiped with the necessary resources to run eclipse ;-)

EDIT: Sorry that I had the impression that this is somekind of fun question (now I have to give a more serious answer).
Assuming you want to create C code:

- You need to download [eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)
- and [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) add the bin directory to you PATH
- create a C project and edit the project properties "C/C++ Build" and set the required options for code generation see

[GCC PDP Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/PDP_002d11-Options.html) for options like

> ```
> -munix-asm
> Use Unix assembler syntax. This is the default when configured for
> ```
>
> `pdp11-*-bsd'.
>
> ```
> -mdec-asm
> Use DEC assembler syntax. This is the default when configured for any
> ```
>
> PDP-11 target other than
>   `pdp11-*-bsd'.

Hope this helps. Maybe you need some additional packages for gcc, since I don't believe it comes with PDP features out of the box.

Comment: I think we wants to *cross-compile*, so that he can generate PDP-11 assembly source from C code (although Zeus only knows *why* anyone would want to do this)

Comment: exactly, so what do I need to do?